# What are all the weapons in Nitrome Must Die?

Tags: nitrome-must-die

In Nitrome's 100th game, [Nitrome Must Die](http://www.nitrome.com/games/nitromemustdie/index.html), there are a lot of weapons. In the first few levels you see your basic Machinegun, Pistol, Shotgun... but then you start to get cool referential weaponry. Like the *Chisel* of the eponymous game, or the *Fireball* from their Trap series. And you play further and find the arrow weapons each from Bow Contest and Twin Shot. Each day that I play the game, I end up running into a handful of new weapons. There are *a lot* of weapons.

Can someone produce a list of all of the weapons in the game? Would be excellent if it sourced the ones that are references, but that's not as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Nitrome wiki](http://nitrome.wikia.com/wiki/Nitrome_Must_Die!!!!):

> Nitrome Must Die has over 40 weapons. Below is a list of them:
>
> - Bang†
> - Banana Bomb
> - Barrel
> - BC Bow
> - Boomerang
> - Bubble
> - Bullethead
> - Buzz Saw
> - Canary
> - Chisel
> - Cluster Bomb
> - Dragon Ball
> - Fart
> - Fireball
> - Helmet
> - Homing Missile
> - Machine Gun
> - Mega Laser
> - Mine
> - Mini Gun
> - Molotov
> - Nanobot
> - Ninja Star
> - Nitro
> - Nitrome
> - Penguin
> - Pea Shooter
> - Pistol
> - Pixel Gun
> - Points
> - Rocket
> - Shotgun
> - Slap
> - Spring†
> - Sucker Punch
> - Toast
> - Triple Arrow
> - Twin Shot Arrow
>
> †: Only used in one particular level of its own

Comment: ...huh. I didn't realize there was a Nitrome Wiki, and apparently my search for this data just failed miserably. Now I'd *really* like to see sourcing on all of those weapons, though, so that we'd actually have real cool data.

Comment: @GraceNote Oh, totally. I figured this was just a good start. :)

Comment: Of note, while the wiki tries to cover every weapon in a separate article, it is very sparse on some of them, and also doesn't source every weapon that is a game reference.

Comment: I think the boomerang weapon is missing? Or was it just called something non-intuitive?

Comment: @Raven No, it's called Boomerang.